# how to make a div the same height as an image without specifying height while using floats

Tags: css, flexbox

I would like to achieve this for mobile and desktop, here's the
[dev image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6SDj.png).
This is the basis of what I have:

```css
.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .image {
    float: right;
  }
  .text {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container clear">
  <div class="image"><img src="some-image" /></div>
  <div class="text">some text</div>
</div>
```

I realize that flexbox doesn't like floats at all, but I would like the content to stack for mobile, and change positions for the media query.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add width to your elements?
If so, you can specify an absolute position for the text element, and by setting "top: 100%;" in mobile and "height: 100%;" in both mobile and desktop should do the trick.

Something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .container {
        position: relative;
        width: 90%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .image {
        width: 100%;
        background: blue;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .text {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 2;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: red;
        text-align: center;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
        .container {
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .image {
            width: 50%;
            float: right;
        }

        .text {
            top: auto;
            left: auto;
            width: 50%;
            float: left;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

In your situation, you can use bootstrap. Bootstrap have grid system allow you do with minimum coding.
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Comment: Don't submit a link-only answer. Either give OP a code solution from the link, or just leave this as a comment to their post.